# Grafana Telegram alert issue Failed to Send alert notifications

Tags: docker, devops, telegram, alert, grafana

I am trying to setup telegram notification on Grafana but I am getting this error

[image]

Test fails to send notification.
Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:1.4.1
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:1.4.1
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers
      - /var/www/nt_devops/monitoring/docker-config.yml:/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/docker-config.yml

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:master
    ports:
      - "9095:3000"
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - grafana:/etc/grafana
   

volumes:
  grafana_data:
  grafana:
```

Here is my grafana container logs

```
2-23T05:11:55+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=POST path=/api/alert-notifications/test status=500 remote_addr=10.0.0.2 time_ms=35 size=48 referer=https://grafana.example.com/alerting/notification/1/edit
t=2022-02-23T05:11:58+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/live/ws status=0 remote_addr=10.0.0.2 time_ms=1 size=0 referer=
t=2022-02-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending telegram notification" logger=alerting.notifier.telegram chat_id=-654204299 bot_token=5145999542:AAH16mk4Vh__sHh9JMnhdoNtELbRuuflbI4 apiAction=sendMessage
t=2022-02-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send webhook" logger=alerting.notifier.telegram error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request" webhook=grafana_telegram
t=2022-02-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request"
t=2022-02-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request"
t=2022-02-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send alert notifications" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request" remote_addr=10.0.0.2

2-23T05:12:00+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=POST path=/api/alert-notifications/test status=500 remote_addr=10.0.0.2 time_ms=34 size=48 referer=https://grafana.example.com/alerting/notification/1/edit
t=2022-02-23T05:16:36+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending telegram notification" logger=alerting.notifier.telegram chat_id=-654204299 bot_token=5145999542:AAH16mk4Vh__sHh9JMnhdoNtELbRuuflbI4 apiAction=sendMessage
t=2022-02-23T05:16:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send webhook" logger=alerting.notifier.telegram error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request" webhook=grafana_telegram
t=2022-02-23T05:16:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request"
t=2022-02-23T05:16:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request"
t=2022-02-23T05:16:36+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send alert notifications" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="Webhook response status 400 Bad Request" remote_addr=10.0.0.2
```

I am using host network no any other networks. I think it is networking issue

Here is browser console errors

[image]

Comment: This is worked after a while but why I don't know